# How to Disable a TextBox in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textbox

I tried to disabled a textbox, but it doesn't work as expected. The following is my code

the disabling command:

```
JavascriptExecutor js =    (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("textbox"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('disabled', '');", textbox );
```

the testing command:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'Text Box Enalbled !! ');", textbox );
```

Comment: what is the type of `js` object?

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ it is a `JavascriptExecutor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[For disable text box](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_disabled.asp), you need to set `.disabled` property of the `textbox` to `true` as below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("textbox"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].disabled = true", textbox);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String todisable = "document.getElementsById('textbox')[0].setAttribute('disabled', '');";
javascript.executeScript(todisable);
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable the textbox in javascript you can do:

```
JavascriptExecutor js =    (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('textbox').setAttribute('disabled', '');");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('name').value='singh'");
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes.